# How to send json data to jquery

Tags: jquery, array, json

I have a question, that i would like to send some array to jquery once someone clicked on specific element, i can see that i can not add array to any input, so i decided to encode array in json. But i am stuck there as i am not able to get that json data from that input field in jquery. I am getting that json data in jquery using field class name.

Please someone help as i am building a WP shortcode and i want to send all attributes to jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these. It would give you json data.

```
$data = json_encode( array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'success');
$result = wp_send_json_success( array( 'photo_id' => $photo_id_encode,'upload_msg' => 'Success' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already found the solution as i was using input field to send json array to jquery instead now i am using hidden div and having json array as text of div. Thanks again for your help